# What is the equivalent of Spring Interceptors/Filters in the Django framework

Tags: django, spring

I need to intercept the request/response similar to how it is done in java filters. What is the best way of doing this in Django? Am I just going to create write my own middleware or does something else already exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create your own middleware if you need to intercept client request/response.

Use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/) if you want to intercept model changes.